# Registering DLLs and .TLBs

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am working for a company that registers a lot of COM DLLs in the System32 folder/SYSWOW64 folder.  I recall a question some time ago where Hans Passent said that this is wrong as the folders specified are for Windows DLLs.  I cannot find the post so I want to check that this is correct?

Also if I want to register a COM DLL or a TypeLibrary in a foreign folder then can I just use the following command (for COM):

regsvr32 app.dll

Finally I was reading about the CODEBASE flag of Regasm: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?597928-RESOLVED-How-to-delete-a-VB6-Reference.  Do you have to use this flag if you want to register a TypeLibrary (.TLB)? What happens if you .NET assembly uses a third party library that is not signed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about *installing* COM DLLs in the System folder, then you are correct. All applications, and their support libraries, should be installed under the Program Files folders, or the Common Program Files folders.

You are also correct that REGSVR32.EXE can be used to *manually* register DLLs and OCX. "Foreign folder" is not a Windows concept - you can register a component *anywhere* in the file system, including the Windows and Windows System folders. By the way, if you use an installer, then you shouldn't have to use REGSVR32.EXE.

However, TLB files cannot be registered with REGSVR32.EXE, because that application basically loads the DLL/OCX, and calls an exported function on the library, so effectively the library registers itself. Instead, you need another tool, e.g. REGTLIB.

You don't use /CODEBASE to register a raw type library, because REGASM is used for registering .NET DLLs as COM components, not TLB files.

Comment: In theory only Microsoft-supplied DLLs go into the System folder.  A 3rd party should be supplying their developer customers with an associated .DEP file that identifies the proper install location, subdependencies, and other things - all put in place using a "developer" installer and not a bag file raw files.  Even so, many 3rd party suppliers got in the bad habit of targeting the System folder too.  When they provide a .DEP file it also points there.  This is a mistake, but that's life!  As for .TLB files, normally those are only needed on development workstations.

Comment: Sheesh, edit error above.  Should have read "a bag of raw files" where a "bag" would be a ZIP archive or something, leaving you on your own about file placement and library registration.